# Find the eigenvalue of an $n \times n$ matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Suppose that $Au = 10u +3v$, $Av = -3u+2v$, $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, find two eigenvalues of it.

The method I tried:

1. $u,v$ span an invariant subspace of $R^n$, but this seems not helpful.
2. I tried to calculate $A(k_1u+k_2v) = a(10k_1u-3k_1u+3k_2v+2k_2v)$, but I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: A raw question without comment is for us (maybe we are wrong in your case...) a sign that no work has been done on the subject. I vote to close.

Comment: Hi tate!  Looks like you're new here.  We expect questions to include at least a little bit of context.  It would help us (and make it more likely for your question to be reopened, assuming it's closed) if you [edit]ed your question to address any of the following: what have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?  Where did you encounter the problem?  Are there any techniques or theorems that you expected to use for this problem?

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: It looks like you're on your way to getting the question reopened (it will take some time; the process requires 5 votes).  In the mean time: there are two approaches I can think of.  One does a lot with the idea of an invariant subspace, the other hinges on "the matrix of a transformation with respect to a basis" (e.g. $[T]_{\mathcal B}$).  On that first approach: you might have a theorem (somewhere in your notes/textbook) which states that if $U$ is an invariant subspace of the linear transformation $T$, then any eigenvalues of $T|_{U}$ are eigenvalues of $T$. Does that sound familiar?

Comment: So I can directly view $A$ as a $2 \times 2$ matrix, and calculate its eigenvalues, right?

Comment: Well, you can view *the restriction of $A$ to a 2-dimensional invariant subspace* as a $2 \times 2$ matrix.  The eigenvalues of this restriction are also eigenvalues of the overall matrix.  Note also that the subspace is only $2$-dimensional if $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent.  But you have the right idea: calculating the eigenvalues of the small matrix you get gives you eigenvalues from the original.

Comment: I see, that is very helpful!!! Thank you very much!!